# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS when I download file from AmazonS3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, download

Got java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS when executing the following code segment.

```
S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName));

InputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(object.getObjectContent());
File file = new File(filePathToDownload);      
OutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
int read = -1;
while ( ( read = reader.read() ) != -1 ) {
         writer.write(read);
}

writer.flush();
writer.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS

Comment: posting the stack trace would be help to isolate the issue

Comment: Have a look at [this pull request](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/issues/12). It seems a conflicting version in the Jackson library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my error by providing proper credential and client configuration in AmazonS3 initialization. Thanks for your support guys.

Comment: can you provide a code snippet of how you setup the client configuration? I know it's sort of a noob question but if you can help me out. would be great